# How can I access a node's menu link and weight through EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database

In D7, I'm trying to set up a custom menu that is ordered by the weight of the node->path ("weight" field in table menu_links). How can I access the node's path's weight value in my query so it can be ordered correctly? This is what I had but was shot down very quickly:

```
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('field_meeting', 'value', $meetid, '=')
    -> propertyOrderBy('weight','ASC')    
    ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.
    $result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: You can't without altering the query at a later stage (`hook_query_alter()`). You can only get entity properties and fields by default with an `EntityFieldQuery`, nothing that would require joining in other tables

Comment: Thanks very much Clive! When you say later stage, any way I run the order immediately after the execute? Looking at the query_alter code I am not quite sure if I have to call it outside my module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using db_query JOIN to get the info straight from the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT menu_links.link_path, menu_links.link_title, menu_links.weight, node.nid 
        FROM menu_links
        JOIN node.nid
        ON menu_links.link_path LIKE CONCAT('node/', node.nid)
        ORDER BY menu_links.weight ASC";
$result = db_query($sql);
```